# Paypal Integration in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, paypal

Do we hav Paypal API for Blackberry as like the iPhone and Android. I have android PayPal API here https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile/mep.

But i cant able to find it for Blackberry.

Please help me whether paypal transfer can be made in Blackberry or not.

Comment: you implemented paypal in blackberry ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by using this sdk https://www.x.com/community/ppx/sdks#WSDL

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't a BlackBerry specific Paypal API.

So to get around this, we just launched the browser to the Paypal link. From there they could enter their Paypal credentials and pay as if they were using a desktop browser. It's not as clean as using an API though.

If you're looking for a cleaner solution, you could try creating a Paypal API wrapper for example using PHP, which is used by a proxy page. Then in the BlackBerry, use standard HTTP requests to send GET/POST requests to the proxy page. The proxy page will in turn use the wrapper you created to set up payment for you and your customer. This way you won't necessarily have to leave the application.