# Payment service in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, paypal

I am developing one application which want to transfer amount one account to another. is there any payment api for BlackBerry like Paypal api in  Android and Iphone?   If not, what alternatives are there for transfer amount from within a My Blackberry Apllication?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paypal Integration in Blackberry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471173/paypal-integration-in-blackberry)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this previous post
[Paypal Integration in Blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471173/paypal-integration-in-blackberry)

Answer (score 0):

RIM now offers a [BlackBerry Payment Service SDK](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/platform/paymentservice.jsp). I don't know if you can transfer money from one account to another, but you can accept in-app payments.